# NodeJS Encryption/Decryption of Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am currently working on an application which is supposed to become some sort of dropbox clone. The idea is that I can upload and download files, but while the file is stored on the server it should be encrypted.

I have already developed a nodejs backend. The backend uses express to communicate with the frontend, which is a React application with axios.

The up- and download works fine. I use js-file-download and a simple input tag to upload files.

My problem is now the encrypting/decrypting part. All the libraries and examples I found only work with strings or objects but not with files. Somehow I don't understand how to take a whole file like I have it in my code, extract the information, encrypt it and store it again in the file. Could somebody help me a little bit?

Below you can see the code snippets to up- and download code from the frontend. I think there are the best places to en- and decrypt.

Code to upload files

```js
const uploadHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if(files.length === 0){
      props.handleError('No files!', 5000)
    }else if(checkMimeType()){
      console.log('start uploading')
      const data = new FormData()
      for(var x = 0; x<files.length; x++) {
        data.append('file', files[x])
      }
      const response = await fileService.sendFiles(data)
      if(response.status === 200){
        props.handleNotification(response.data, 5000)
        props.getFiles()
      }
      else{
        props.handleError(response.data, 5000)
      }
      setFiles([])
    }
    window.location.reload()
  }

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setFiles(event.target.files)
  }

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-15'>
          <div className='form-group files' >
            <Form method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' onSubmit={uploadHandler} >
              <input type='file' autoComplete='off' name='files' multiple onChange=    {onChangeHandler}/>
              <Button className='button' type="submit">Upload</Button>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Code to download files:

```js
  const fileDownload = require('js-file-download')

  const handleSingleDownload = async (file) => {
    const response = await fileService.getFile(file.id)
    console.log(response.data)
    fileDownload(response.data, file.name)
    props.handleNotification('Download started...', 2500)

  }
```

Comment: Is it what you are looking for ? https://medium.com/@brandonstilson/lets-encrypt-files-with-node-85037bea8c0e

Comment: Kinda. Read and write streams indicates that the file has to be stored on the server. When I upload it, it is not stored yet. I also would like to handle it in the frontend and not backend. Although If I can't find an alternative I will just store the file first, then create a stream and encrypt it.